# cd won't work in bash script in linux server?

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I have deploy.sh and this is the content.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@202.119.36.10
cd ../var/www/myProject
```

I run `bash deploy.sh`
the cd part is not working? The idea is to automate my deployment, now I have to manually go to the directory, do git pull and restart my node server.

Comment: How do you know it's not working? You are doing a `cd ..`, which directory are you starting from (generally `root` starts at the base directory, for which there is no `..`). Why do you add the tags `Linux` and `MacOS`, and why `Javascript`?

Comment: The base directory for root is in most cases `/root`, so `/root/..` is `/`.

Comment: @hnicke no defaul ssh of most cloud provider set base directory as $HOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script means:

1. Log in to your server.
2. After logging out, run `cd ../var/www/myProject` command on your computer.

You can put all commands in the [Here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document)

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@202.119.36.10 <<EOF
cd /var/www/myProject
EOF
```

Normally, if we switch to the system folders, like `/var`, `/etc`, we use the absolute path.

Or, put all commands that you want to execute on the server in a script file.

The content of file **deploy.sh**:

```
cd /var/www/myProject
```

Copy this script to your server, and run it:

```
scp deploy.sh root@202.119.36.10:
ssh root@202.119.36.10 bash deploy.sh
```

Or run the script via here-document

```
ssh root@202.119.36.10 bash < deploy.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion It's wrong idea to go and ssh to server ( which i did that earlier )

> You can run CI/CD Environment that can do it for you as you push your
>   code to the server ( GitLab or etc. ) and it will trigger your bash
>   inside your saver ( as you configure it ) and it will run your command
>   and finally deploy your product.

Here you can learn more : [GitLab CI/CD](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/)

Comment: I just want a semi automated without ci/cd tooling

Comment: Ok, let me answer first one

Comment: You can issue `pwd` command in your **bash file** _to ensure you are in the right folder_ and _check if `cd` is working or not_

Answer (score 0):

That `cd` command will run on your local machine, not the remote one.

What's happening here is that you're opening an ssh connection, then the script blocks waiting for commands to that ssh connection, which you never send. Then when the ssh command returns (which, again, never happens) you would do a `cd` directly on your machine.

A way to do this would be to have a file consisting of the commands you want to launch on the server and pipe it to the ssh command, like this.

```
ssh root@202.119.36.10 < commands
```

Where `commands` is a file containing, e.g.

```
cd ../var/www/myProject
```

Otherwise, you could have `commands` on the remote machine and call it from your local machine (assuming that `commands` is in root's path in the remote machine).

```
ssh root@202.119.36.10 'commands'
```

This, of course, assumes that you're doing a no-password login to the remote machine (for example, with an ssl key file).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "deploying"
ssh root@202.119.36.10 'bash' < ./commands.sh
```

So you can put all of your commands in commands.sh file as follow

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
cd ../var/www/myProject
```

Comment: why do I need 2 files?

Comment: You can do it in one file with 
    `ssh root@202.119.36.10 <<EOF
    cd /var/www/myProject
    EOF`
but I keep it in 2 files for clear separation of operations

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue, this is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh root@server_ip << 'COMMAND'
cd ../var/www/myProject
git pull
npm i
pm2 restart server
COMMAND
```